# Wrong 'new post'-animation in dark-mode

Tags: bug, dark-mode

**Bug description**

As the example below shows, the enter-animation of a new question on Stackoverflow does not seem to adjust to dark-mode.

The animation is triggered when I enter the 'First posts' and 'Late answer' page, which can be found in the review queue for users who have this functionality enabled. I don't know (yet) whether there are more pages where this occurs and whether it is just me that sees this strange behavior.

It's not a disaster, but would like to see it fixed

---

**Example (GIF)**

[image: The animation as shown on the website]